# Problem with mysql/data folder is too big and took the whole place

Tags: mysql, aws, phpmyadmin, wordpress, ssh

for the first time I am faced with such a problem that has puzzled everyone.

I have all hosting busy (AWS lightsail) 78GB and after a few analyzes I realized that 90% of the memory is occupied in the `mysql/data` folder.

My wordpress website is weight - 6GB and I removed all binary logs before the problem, so the problem is not connected with that.

I can no longer log into *phpmyadmin*, because there is no free space left on the disk. But when I got there until the problem I saw that `wp-option` has a crazy amount of `GB`. No plugin was able to clear this and I decided to put it off.

Now that everything is busy, most of the commands cannot be executed, especially the mysql commands. I am using `SSH`. Help if possible.

Comment: since absolutely everything is busy, the only way to connect to mysql is via SSH (phpmyadmin is no longer possible to log in due to memory), but even so, not a single cleanup command works, and they give only one reason - there is no space to execute that command.

Comment: "memory" is not "disk"; please check your use of terminology.

Comment: Dear James Rick. I literally wrote what I saw in SSH after my command. If you have any concerns, please write this to the bitnami team. I have already contacted with them to fix similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the size of your tablespace, use this procedure:

1. Use mysqldump to dump all your InnoDB tables.
2. Stop the server.
3. Remove all the existing tablespace files, including the ibdata and ib_log files. If you want to keep a backup copy of the information, then copy all the ib* files to another location before the removing the files in your MySQL installation.
4. Remove any .frm files for InnoDB tables.
5. Configure a new tablespace.
6. Restart the server.
7. Import the dump files.

after you restore database, the storage costed will shrink a lot.Due to mvcc and page splitting,the data storage space will grow much during db working process.

Comment: Since you are using AWS, it might be easier to export/import the data to a new instance.